# JSON parsing error in ruby client on Users.messages.attachments.get

Tags: ruby, gmail-api, google-client

gem 'google-api-client', '~> 0.7.1'

using ruby google client to call https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/attachments/get it is crashing after i get the result and call result.data

result.rb line 154

data = @request.api_method.response_schema.new(data)

throws JSON::ParseError

757: unexpected token at '"R0lGODlhigKjAOYAAG2Xd9js18jkx........="'

Comment: it looks like maybe your data is base64 encoded

Answer (score 0):

The data field of the attachment is base64 encoded, if you want to access the data field, you should decode it first.

For example you can do the following:

```
attachment_data = result.data
attachment_json = JSON.parse(attachment_data.to_json())
mime_data = Base64.decode64(attachment_json['data'])
```

Or try:

```
mime_data = Base64.decode64(result.data['data'])
```

You might also want to read [this article](http://makandracards.com/makandra/15611-how-to-fix-unexpected-token-error-for-json-parse) about how to parse json correctlu.

Comment: The problem is result.data crashes in the google api client library. I got around the problem with `JSON.parse(result.response.body)`